# How to find matching braces in IDA's decompiled code?

Tags: ida, hexrays

For the source generated by Hex Ray's decompiler in IDA, is it possible to highlight matching braces once I place the pointer at the beginning of a block?

As an example, in the screenshot below, the `if` block begins at line# `263` and ends at line# `269`. What I want is, if I place the cursor at line# `263`, IDA should highlight the block end at line# `269`. Is such a feature available? Many code editors provides similar feature to make code browsing easier for larger blocks of code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this by default. Checkout the [Hexlight](https://www.hex-rays.com/contests/2016/hexlight/hexrays_hlight.py) plugin by Milan Bohacek. It will highlight the line with the matching brace.

Example from Hex-Rays site:
[image]

Comment: It's useless. If you scroll down, the cursor moves from the selection and highlighting doesn't work for large block of code. Thanks though for trying to help me out.

Comment: If you want to go to the end of the block you can hit 'b' at the curly brace.